# Deleting Files in a Folder, but not the Folder

Tags: python

I am encountering with two problems on deleting Files inside a Folder called `Selection`

1. The script is suppose to Delete ONLY Files inside the `Selection` Folder, but it deletes the `Selection` folder as well.
2. The `Selection` folder has been deleted at very beginning of the running of script, bu I put the process at the end. In fact I need to analyze files stored in `Selection`, and after storing the final data in `Final` folder delete all the files inside the `Selection`, but not the folder itself.

Here is the code I am using to the files inside selection

```
for the_file in os.listdir(claendir):
    file_path = os.path.join(claendir, the_file)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            os.unlink(file_path)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

and here is the entire code

```
import arcpy, shutil
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:\\GISData\\Data"
InFeaturePath = "C:\\GISData\\Data\\"
claendir='C:\\GISData\\Selection\\'
shutil.rmtree(claendir);
InFeatureName = "band-tailed_pigeon.shp"
coulmn = "PataMN_1"
OutFeatureName ="HornedLark.shp"
InFeature = InFeaturePath + InFeatureName
OutFeaturePath ="C:\\GISData\\Final\\"
OutFeature = OutFeaturePath + OutFeatureName
dropFields = ["id","WTRSHD_FID"]

select_1 = "selected_1.shp"
select_2 = "selected_2.shp"
select_3 = "selected_3.shp"
select_4 = "selected_4.shp"
select_5 = "selected_5.shp"
dissolve_1 = "dissolved_1.shp"
dissolve_2 = "dissolved_2.shp"
dissolve_3 = "dissolved_3.shp"
dissolve_4 = "dissolved_4.shp"
dissolve_5 = "dissolved_5.shp"


# Process: Select
# Select 1
arcpy.Select_analysis(InFeature, select_1,  coulmn+ " <= 0.200000")
# Select 2
arcpy.Select_analysis(InFeature, select_2,  coulmn+ ">= 0.200001 AND " +coulmn+ " <= 0.400000")
# Select 3
arcpy.Select_analysis(InFeature, select_3,  coulmn+ ">= 0.400001 AND " +coulmn+ " <= 0.600000")
# Select 4
arcpy.Select_analysis(InFeature, select_4,  coulmn+ ">= 0.600001 AND " +coulmn+ " <= 0.800000")
# Select 5
arcpy.Select_analysis(InFeature, select_5,  coulmn+ ">= 0.800001 AND " +coulmn+ " <= 1")


# Process: Dissolve
# Dissolve 1
arcpy.Dissolve_management(select_1, dissolve_1, "", "", "MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
print "Disolve 1 Finished"
# Dissolve 2
arcpy.Dissolve_management(select_2, dissolve_2, "", "", "MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
print "Disolve 2 Finished"
# Dissolve 3
arcpy.Dissolve_management(select_3, dissolve_3, "", "", "MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
print "Disolve 3 Finished"
# Dissolve 4
arcpy.Dissolve_management(select_4, dissolve_4, "", "", "MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
print "Disolve 4 Finished"
# Dissolve 5
arcpy.Dissolve_management(select_5, dissolve_5, "", "", "MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
print "Disolve 5 Finished"

print "Add Field Started ...."
# Process: Add Field
# Add Field 1
arcpy.AddField_management(dissolve_1, "type", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
# Add Field 2
arcpy.AddField_management(dissolve_2, "type", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
# Add Field 3
arcpy.AddField_management(dissolve_3, "type", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
# Add Field 4
arcpy.AddField_management(dissolve_4, "type", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
# Add Field 5
arcpy.AddField_management(dissolve_5, "type", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

print "Add Field End "
print "Calculate Field Started ...."
# Process: Calculate Field
# Calculate Field 1
arcpy.CalculateField_management(dissolve_1, "type", "1", "VB", "")
# Calculate Field 2
arcpy.CalculateField_management(dissolve_2, "type", "2", "VB", "")
# Calculate Field 3
arcpy.CalculateField_management(dissolve_3, "type", "3", "VB", "")
# Calculate Field 4
arcpy.CalculateField_management(dissolve_4, "type", "4", "VB", "")
# Calculate Field 5
arcpy.CalculateField_management(dissolve_5, "type", "5", "VB", "")
print "Calculate Field End"
print "Delete Field Started ...."
# Process: Delete Extra Field
# Delete Field 1
arcpy.DeleteField_management(dissolve_1, dropFields)
# Delete Field 2
arcpy.DeleteField_management(dissolve_2, dropFields)
# Delete Field 3
arcpy.DeleteField_management(dissolve_3, dropFields)
# Delete Field 4
arcpy.DeleteField_management(dissolve_4, dropFields)
# Delete Field 5
arcpy.DeleteField_management(dissolve_5, dropFields)
print "Delete Field End"

print "Merge Started ...."
# Process: Merge
inFeaturesToMerge = [dissolve_1, dissolve_2, dissolve_3, dissolve_4, dissolve_5]
arcpy.Merge_management(inFeaturesToMerge, OutFeature)

for the_file in os.listdir(claendir):
    file_path = os.path.join(claendir, the_file)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            os.unlink(file_path)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

Once again I need to delete ONLY files inside the `Selection` folder (and not the folder) and do this after finishing all analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this on line 8 of your full code:

```
shutil.rmtree(claendir);
```

This deletes `claendir` and everything below it.